# General questions regarding SVD decomposition of matrices

Tags: matrices

The Singular Value decomposition of a matrix is

$$A= U\Sigma V^H$$

I was reading a paper and the paper stated that the SVD was

$$A'= V\Sigma V^H$$

1- I am wondering how come the right singular matrix and the left singlular matrix are the same (expect ofcourse transpose). Does this mean $A'$ is a special type of matrix.

2- Is it correct to say that the vectors of $V$ are orthogonal that is $v_iv_j^H=0$ for $i\neq j$?

Thanks

Comment: 1) $A'$ needs to be hermitian. 2) $v_i^H v_j$

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel oh yes. silly me

Comment: @user251257 actually silly *me*. It must be hermitian of course and in addition positive semidefinite.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel oh yes, $\Sigma$ is positive semidefinite by definition... I should get some sleep.